# ConcurrentModificationException with recursive use of Maps in Java

Tags: java, recursion, dictionary, concurrency, agent

We are creating a tree structure made up of AID's from JADE Agent structures.  We chose to do it recursively so that the code can be executed no matter how many Agents are currently in the system, the tree structure can be dynamically altered to fit the number of agents currently in the system.  I am not sure it some sort of lock needs to be set in place to ensure that the `Map` object is read from and written to without damaging the integrity of the structure.

Here is the code that is causing the issue.

```
// BuildHierarchy method used to create the hierarchy based on Monitor Agents in the system
private void BuildHierarchy(Map<AID, Double>freqList, ArrayList<AID> childless, DefaultMutableTreeNode node){
    int i = 0;
    //creates an iterator for the freqList
    Iterator iter = freqList.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()&& i < 2){

        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)iter.next();   
        //if (i<2){ 
            setParentNode((AID)pairs.getKey(), node);
        //}
        freqList.remove(pairs.getKey());
        i++;
    }
    BuildHierarchy(freqList, childless, node.getNextNode());
    BuildHierarchy(freqList, childless, node.getNextNode().getNextSibling());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the `Set` (or the underlying `Map`) while you are iterating over it, except by the iterator's own `remove` operation, or else a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown.  Try

```
iter.remove();
```

instead of

```
freqList.remove(pairs.getKey());
```

Answer (score 0):

When a Iterator is created over a implemented collection a backing set is created on it and there's a counter which keeps a track of the implemented collection size . During the iteration if the set is modified  say "freqList.remove(pairs.getKey());" then it will remove the element and the size of the set is reduced and now when the next time iterator calls next() operation on it , it senses the set is been modified from the counter instance and throws a ConcurrentModificationException . Following code for HashIterator class will give you a clear idea about how it works

```
     final Entry<K,V> nextEntry() {
      if (modCount != expectedModCount)
             throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
         Entry<K,V> e = next;
         if (e == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

         if ((next = e.next) == null) {
            Entry[] t = table;
            while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null)
                 ;
         }
        current = e;
        return e;
     }
```

if the entry is removed using the actual collection then modcount !=expectedCount will be true and it will throw a exception .